# Need to evaluate not variable itself but value as new variable in if-statement

Tags: bash

I'm working on a function that checks if certain packages are installed and prefers own builds, which paths are stored in a config file.

So the function get's an input like

```
rsync
```

It then proceeds to form a new variable called

```
$bin_variable_name
```

which has the value

```
RSYNC_BIN
```

In the config-file mentioned above could be a line like this.

```
RSYNC_BIN="/home/<username>/Software/rsync"
```

So if this file is sourced at the beginning of the function, the variable $RSYNC_BIN has a value other than ''.

I now need to check this in an if-statement. Unfortunately I cannot reference $RSYNC_BIN directly since the function should work with any given input. So I somehow need to "evaluate"

```
$bin_variable_name
```

inside the if-statement, so that bash doesn't executes

```
if [[ $bin_variable_name == '' ]]; then ...
```

but rather

```
if [[ $<whatever comes from $bin_variable_name>_BIN = '' ]]; then ...
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables)

```
$ bin_variable_name=RSYNC_BIN
$ RSYNC_BIN="/home/<username>/Software/rsync"
$ echo "${!bin_variable_name}"
/home/<username>/Software/rsync
```